# How do I modify magits behavior to use the date that I finalize the commit and not the date that I start the commit

Tags: magit, git

Desired Solution: I want magit to make a commit with a datetime set to the time that I "create" the commit, not the time that I start the commit "creation" flow.

**Background:**

So committing in magit in general follows these steps:

1. `S` Stages all files.
2. `c c` Initiates a commit, then write the message in the "commit buffer".
3. `C-c C-c` to actually create the commit.

The thing that surprises me is that the datetime of the created commit is actually the datetime that I pressed `c c`, NOT the time that I pressed `C-c C-c`. I find this very annoying as I am trying to be better about writing more detailed commits (often spending a few minutes on them). The date of the commit does not reflect when I actually *created* the commit, it instead reflects when I *started* the commit.

**Details**:

Why do I care about being off by a few minutes? Because I am recording videos as I work and would like to slice them at the commit points. However, the commit points are all a few minutes before the actual commit was made in the video. This is kind of annoying.

Comment: Given that editing the transient suffix to overide author date won't make a difference for you, setting up `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` and/or `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`environment variables is the only way I know. I'd use `git-commit-setup-hook` to set it up to current value. This isn't perfect and reasons are explained in the manual, but less messy than automatically amend each commit.

Comment: Please note that this is not "Magit's behaviour" -- the issue has nothing to do with Magit. It is no different if you run `git commit` from the command line -- git will invoke whatever editor you have configured, and ultimately the commit timestamp will be the point at which you invoked the command, not the point at which you finished editing the message.  Magit simply arranges (via its `with-editor` magic) that the editor invoked by git will be the Emacs instance you're using at the time; but it's still just calling `git commit`, and the commit timestamp is entirely subject to that.

Comment: You could, of course, log a bug report for git, if you feel that behaviour is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that this is Git behavior and not Magit behavior. I always either use Magit or use `git commit -m "<message>"` and so thought it was something being introduced by Magit. I do find the default behavior a bit funny. It is strange that the recorded "time" of something is actually before the commit finalized. However, I also recognize that the hash is partially time dependent, and how could you build the hash if you can't "freeze" the commit time? Seems a bit odd, but at the same time, I get it. Anyway, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Seeing as how the commit message is also a part of the hashed data, I don't think that's the reason.  It seems like a fair question to ask upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`magit-commit-reshelve` on <kbd>c n</kbd> is intended for that use-case. [Well not your very specific use-case in particular, more the general idea.] It is disabled by default; see [Enabling and Disabling Suffixes](https://magit.vc/manual/transient/Enabling-and-Disabling-Suffixes.html).

A multi-commit variant exists as well; `magit-reshelve-since` on <kbd>r t</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the problem was to register a post-commit hook that "nudged" the commit & author date. It has the possibility of running endlessly, but on my machine it only runs once or twice. Anyway, it does set the commit time to be immediately after I submit my commit message.

```
#!/bin/sh

STR1=$(git log -1 --format=%cd --date=iso | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
STR2=$(date --iso-8601=seconds | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
if [ "$STR1" != "$STR2" ]; then
    sleep 0.1s
    git commit --amend --no-edit --date=now
fi
```

[Source Code Here](https://github.com/samedhi/commit-to-video/blob/master/post-commit)